# Project 'mymodule' not found in root project 'mymodule'

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I configured a gradle project so it builds submodules when I run `./gradlew build` and it goes flawless. But when I move to a subdirectory and run a submodule like `./gradlew :mymodule:build` I get the error

```
Project 'mymodule' not found in root project 'mymodule'.
```

My grade root config:

```
group 'com.example.core'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    version = '1.0'
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${spring_boot_version}"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
}

project(':mymodule1') {
    apply plugin: 'application'

    bootRepackage {
        mainClass = 'com.example.App'
    }

    springBoot {
        mainClass = 'com.example.App'
        executable = true
        buildInfo()
    }

    bootRun {
        addResources = false
    }

    task stage(dependsOn: 'bootRepackage') {
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':mymodule2')
    }

}

project(':mymodule2') {
    apply plugin: 'application'
    // config module
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        // repos
    }
    dependencies {
        // deps
    }
}


defaultTasks 'bootRun'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

clean {
    delete "target"
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/resources'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.0'
}

bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

And I have almost empty module's config in the submodule:

```
group 'com.example.proj'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

I suggest a reason is in missing of a run configuration for the submodule. So the question is how to point submodule's `build.gralde` use the parent's configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem was in wrong auto-configuration of the project in IntelliJ IDEA.

It configured like this:

[image]

But it is required this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Needless to move into the subdirectory, juste run `./gradlew :mymodule:build` from the root directory.

The `:mymodule` prefix already indicates that your want to run the specified task (here `build`) for a target subproject (here `mymodule`)

Comment: What about dependencies and configurations? If I store them in the root then I don't need to point them in submodules.

Comment: Some config can be put in the root, other config makes more sense in the module build.gradle. Dependencies work best in each submodule build.gradle, but (again) can be found in the root if that makes sense. See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html